# Chef Update chef_server_url at 'client.rb' using recipe after Chef Server migration

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I want to move my old Chef server to new server and I already succeed to backup the server and restore it to the new server and I migrated 1 computer successfully (manually edited the `chef_server_url` at `client.rb`).

Because I have a lot of computers managed by the old Chef Server I need a scalable way to update the `client.rb` of the computers managed by this server and update the chef_server_url to the new url

My **client.rb** looks like this:

```
`chef_server_url  "https://myfirstdomain:1234"
validation_client_name "chef-validator"
file_cache_path   "c:/chef/cache"
file_backup_path  "c:/chef/backup"
cache_options     ({:path => "c:/chef/cache/checksums", :skip_expires => true})
node_name "mycomp"
log_level        :info
log_location       STDOUT
trusted_certs_dir "c:/chef/trusted_certs"
`

and I need to change it to this:

`chef_server_url  "https://seconddomain:1234"
validation_client_name "chef-validator"
file_cache_path   "c:/chef/cache"
file_backup_path  "c:/chef/backup"
cache_options     ({:path => "c:/chef/cache/checksums", :skip_expires => true})
node_name "mycomp"
log_level        :info
log_location       STDOUT
trusted_certs_dir "c:/chef/trusted_certs"
`
```

I tried to follow the instructions here:
https://getchef.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/206692583-Change-Hostname-of-Chef-Server
But I failed to figure out how to do this step:

> "If you are using the chef-client cookbook to manage your nodes'
>   client.rb file then you could try just setting the
>   node['chef_client']['server_url'] attribute to the new hostname and
>   test to see if the next chef-client run on a node properly changes the
>   client.rb file AND restarts the chef-client service."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the provided instruction, you need to use [`chef-client`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-client/#usage) cookbook to apply this method, it can manage `client.rb` for you. You can upload a recipe to the old server with new server url and run it on all the nodes.

If you do not want to use it, you may consider running [`knife winrm`](https://docs.chef.io/plugin_knife_windows.html#winrm) with some command which will replace the url.

I am not sure if there is some kind of `sed` replacement on windows.